# Export Word to PDF with C# and Word Interop don't export links to bookmarks in document

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have a program in C# where I create a report in .docx using Word Interop. This document is created perfectly with few "headings" with links to bookmarks on pages inside the document and then saved. Then I try to export it to pdf using ExportAsFixedFormat and the exported file includes those "headings" but without links to bookmarks, but in blue color and underlined.

Settings I use for export:

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
                newPdfPath,                                             //output file name
                WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,                       //export format
                false,                                                  //open after export
                WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,           //optimize for
                WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument,                      //export range
                1,                                                      //from
                1,                                                      //to
                WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentWithMarkup,                //export item - only text or include text with markups
                true,                                                   //include dox properties
                true,                                                   //copy information rights management
                WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks,    //export bookmarks and which types
                true,                                                   //include extra data to help screen readers (info about flow and logical organization of content
                true,                                                   //bitmap missing fonts
                false);                                                  //use ISO 19005-1
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

PS: If I open that word document with MS word and export it as PDF manually, then the exported version is as it should be, with all the links in it, so the problem must be in use of ExportAsFixedFormat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, I think we should use `WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF` instead of  `WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF`.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
        using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        string filename = "D:\\1.docx";
        Application app = new Application();
        Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filename);
        doc.Activate();
        object fullname = filename.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
        doc.SaveAs(ref fullname,ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
        ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        ((_Application)app).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Result:
[image]